# Why am I not able to add an event listener in a loop?

Tags: javascript, events

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-input")
for (let element of inputs) {
  element.addEventListener("onchange", e => {
    alert("test")
  })
}
console.log(inputs)
```

When I look at the output of the last line the "onchange" event listener field is null. What am I doing wrong?

Nor does typing into respective input fields produce an alert box.

Comment: What do you mean with *the "onchange" event listener field is null*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *event name* is `change`, not `onchange`:

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-input")
for (let element of inputs) {
  element.addEventListener("change", e => {
    alert("test")
  })
}
console.log(inputs)
```

You would use `onchange` when assigning to the *property name* of `onchange` to add the listener, eg:

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-input")
for (let element of inputs) {
  element.onchange = e => {
    alert("test")
  };
}
console.log(inputs);
```

(but this probably isn't a great idea, because this will overwrite previous listeners attached by assigning to `onchange`, and future code that may assign to `onchange` will overwrite your listener - best to use `addEventListener` instead.)